# Is there a extend mesh generation program link with mathematica such as openfoam native blockmesh?

Tags: mesh

I have read the relative mesh tutorial in mathematica, and found that it mainly focused on finite element method with triangle and tetrahedron, so I wonder if it is possible to link a general extend third party mesh program such as blockmesh embedded in OpenFoam with Mathematica? After all, finite volume method is another important efficient PDE numerical method, specially in CFD area.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with OpenFOAM, but have you looked at e.g. the `ToElementMesh` functions in the ``NDSolve`FEM` `` package? E.g. see this [Finite Element Programming Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). ToElementMesh can certainly produce meshes with non-tetrahedral elements; see e.g. ``Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; ToElementMesh[Cuboid[], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.08]["Wireframe"]`` which returns [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pIClM.png).

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB! Although `ToElementMesh` could deal with hexahedron, it is serve to Finite element method. I hope a generic toolbox which can link to CAD software designing complex geometric model and support general mesh program for next solver and post-process. Openfoam is a siutable platform, but it is mainly for linux and written in c++, so I want a write a mathematica linker to use the function.